# Laravel - Session always expired when redirect to other pages

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, authentication

I having an issues, which is user after login, session will randomly expired when from route to another route.

Comment: show some of your code for better understanding

Comment: driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
'lifetime' => 30,
'table' => 'sessions',
'cookie' => 'myweb_cookies',

Comment: Please provide more information, such as what route you're coming from and going to, a code example would help a lot.

Also please detail what your environment is and how it is set up. 

What configuration are you using for sessions? database? file? redis?

Answer (score 0):

As per i understood from your question
try increasing the expiring time.
"lifetime" => 120,

if this is not the proper answer let me know i will try to help with another.

--edit
try this 
'expire_on_close' => false,

Comment: i tried to put 120 , is still having the same problem.

Comment: Can you please tell what exactly is happening

Comment: my laravel application is working fine on my local, when i upload to live, after user login for awhile, then user will keep logout by system.

Comment: 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'), 'lifetime' => 30, 
'expire_on_close' => false,
'table' => 'sessions', 'cookie' => 'myweb_cookies'

this is my settings.

Comment: Arun Jai, Yes I did it. Will it be possible is because of the high traffic and my server not able to handle it, and causing this problem?

Comment: just increasing the lifetime value to 120 and expire_on_close => false. it won't cause any problem.

Comment: i trying on that, but still having that problem.

Comment: any idea how long it keeps you logged in and how are testing it.

Comment: about 2 minit max, but sometime may less than 1 minit.

Comment: Even i had the same problem and above corrections is what i did to solve the problem. anyways cool. if you solve the problem please update it here. it will help someone.